# Moving multiple files to matching name ones in another disk in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I was downloading a huge torrent (1.2tb with over 6000 folders) divided in 2 parts, so I placed the 2nd part on the designed place and it was not a problem since the master-folder of the torrent is exactly what was needed. The 1st part master-folder was named with some generic torrent name instead of the name I needed, so instead of renaming the torrent name to "source", which I think would have worked and renamed the currently generic name to "source". In files tab I selected all the files and right-click>relocate all of them and bittorrent simply moved all of the files to the same directory, without any subfolder, and created a mess.

So I have a un-finished backup of this torrent and the files are in place, so my idea was using the un-finished one's name, match with the finished ones and put the finished ones in the un-finished matching name's path folder. I hope that was clear.

I tried to resolve this using PowerShell, but I dont know much, so I came up with this and nothing happens, something is wrong. Anyone knows a solution?

```
$itemlistA = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\BitTorrent\" |
ForEach-Object {
    $objnameA = $_.Name
    $objPathA = $_.FullName
}

$itemlistB = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\DesiredPath\" -recurse | 
ForEach-Object{
    $objnameB = $_.Name
    $objPathB = $_.FullName
}

ForEach-Object{ 
    if($objnameA -eq $objnameB){
        Copy-Item -path $objPathA -Destination $objPathB
        Write-Host "ffff    Object ($objnameA) new Path ($objPathB)     ffff"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your intent correctly, the script below will accomplish your goal, assuming your goal is to copy files from a flattened directory into some (potentially) nested directories so that the incoming files overwrite files with matching names.

The O(n^2) performance of the nested loops could be improved with a sort and more efficient search.

You'd need to edit the script's params to reflect your own environment.

```bsh
param(
    $pathToFiles = "$PSScriptRoot\BitTorrent\",
    $desiredPath = "$PSScriptRoot\DesiredPath\"
)

$itemlistA = Get-ChildItem -Path $pathToFiles | Select-Object -Property Name, FullName

$itemlistB = Get-ChildItem -Path $desiredPath -Recurse | Select-Object -Property Name, FullName

foreach ($fileA in $itemlistA) {
    foreach ($fileB in $itemListB) {
        if ($fileB.Name -eq $fileA.Name) {
            Copy-Item -path $fileA.FullName -Destination $fileB.FullName -Verbose
            break
        }
    }
}
```